# Multiple delete from different tables in one script

Tags: postgresql, performance, cascading-deletes

I'm trying to delete datas from a lot of tables. I'm doing it using "begin; ... commit;" but my query is a little bit slow. There's a way to clean up my code and improve this query? I'm using postgress

Here is my actual query:

```
begin;
  delete from table1 where ...
  delete from table2 where ...
  delete from table3 where ...
commit;
```

Comment: Use [truncate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-truncate.html)

Comment: @klin can you show me an example?

Comment: If you want to **empty** many tables: `truncate table1, table2, table3` - that's all.

Comment: @klin no,  i don't want to empty there's a "where" clause on deletes queries

Comment: Ops, misunderstanding. Then I don't see alternatives.

Comment: @klin all right! anyway thanks for try (:

Comment: Try performing VACUUM and ANALYZE on tables before running that query.

Comment: @AnuraagVeerapaneni what does vacuum mean?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-vacuum.html